# Can't find module when unit testing react router 4

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to unit test a simple router system using [react-router 4](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router), and when I try to check if the Component it should render exists, it returns `0`, failing the test.

This is how I setup my test:

```
import React from "react";
import { mount } from "enzyme";
import { MemoryRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import Routes from "./Routes";

import Home from "./view/Home";

describe("Test react router", () => {
    it("Should test for initial route", () => {
        const component = mount(
            <MemoryRouter initialEntries={[ '/' ]} initialIndex={0}>
                <Routes />
            </MemoryRouter>
        )

        expect( component.find(Home).length ).toBe(1);
    })
});
```

However the end result is `0` and not `1`, even if the routing is working just fine when navigating on the page. What am i doing wrong here? Am I doing it right or is there a better aproach to test if the router is rendering what it supposed to be rendering?

Also, what should I be testing on a route? I know the loaded component should be tested separately, so should I just test if the url and component match what it's expected to be?